# Using camera and opencv on mobile device to recognise name on a headstone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, opencv

I'm looking at the possibility of creating an app which will, through the camera on an iphone / ipad / etc., recognise a name on a headstone in a cemetery. It would then match the image (or recognised text) against a stored image / text in a database and call the specific record from that database. 
So for example, there is a database of soldiers who are buried in a particular cemetery. All headstones are laid out in the same format (my avatar is one). If I go to that cemetery with the database installed on (eg) an iPad, and point the camera at a headstone, the soldier's information will be retrieved and displayed on the screen. I imagine something like the system for redeeming an iTunes number, but am not sure. This would 'personalise' the headstone by providing much more detail on the soldier's life and ultimate fate, and could be very useful to people visiting cemeteries for the 100th anniversary of WW1 commemorations. Any suggestions gratefully accepted. Thanks.

Comment: are you already tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea, but I'm not sure why you have come to stack overflow for it as it is an idea, but not a question that people can give you a definitive answer, perhaps this would be better suited on a forum somewhere?

I would suggest you research optical character recognition and using OpenCV to process images as you might be able to achieve the results you want. But aside from that I can't really give you much more information.

Good luck with the project, sounds interesting.